# Hyperlink or textblock with icon and text in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-phone-8

How can i put '<3 like' in a hyperlink in windows phone 8? <3 will be appbar icon.

I have tried to put image in text block but i could not succesful.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the applicationbar sample that is in every new app you create. There you can see how an image is inserted as the background for a button. When the button is clicked you can use the webclient in windows phone to start the hyperlink. 
For doing th hyperlink you have to look into how to create an URL, also. But it is pretty simple.